# vbscript to check if Matlab Runtime Compiler is Installed

Tags: matlab, vbscript, matlab-compiler

I need to write a vbscript to see if "Matlab Compier Runtime" is installed on the system. After searching the internet, I was able to put together the following code:

```
Dim oShell
Dim value

On Error Resume Next

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
value = oShell.RegRead(Key)

If Err.Number = 0 Then
''#Error code 0 indicates success
MsgBox("MCR is installed.")
Else
    MsgBox("MCR is NOT installed.")
End If
```

My problem is, that I am not able to determine what value to assign for 'Key'. I have looked for a key in the Registry Editor and found

'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{3E25C089-6E25-45E4-8C5D-37AD9A33764A}\7.10\0\win32'

but sadly, this does not give me the result. I have also tried

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\runtime\win32

but this is also not giving me he desired result. Note that my inslattation path is

C:\Program Files (x86)\MatLab\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\

My question is, is my key wrong? or is there something I am overlooking in the script?

Comment: I think it would be easier to check the path **"C:\...\Matlab\"** to see if it is installed; rather than going through the registry. If it's not installed are you looking to then execute the installer?

Comment: yes...once I find that the MCR is not installed, I run the installer

Comment: I don't want to check the path because I am not sure what version of windows the user might have and hence there might be different path for different versions...checking registry seems like a more stable option.

Comment: Perhaps you can test whether it works, rather than whether it has been installed?

Comment: @Adnan I guess that depends on whether this program is available in a 64 bit version or not. Either way the most possibilites to check if installed correctly could be three, older versions of windows will be **C:\Program Files** and then in later versions it will either be **x86** or **x64** respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is old (really old), on my machine it is located here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MathWorks\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\7.16
```

So it is `MathWorks` instead of `MatLab`.